# Почему не отправляется форма, когда в адресе обработчика указывается полный путь по правилам Windows?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Имеется простейшая форма, как показано ниже.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <textarea rows="9" cols="30" name="post"></textarea>
    <br />
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Имя обработчика addentry.php.

Если в action написать просто addentry.php, форма срабатывает и перенаправляет на страницу обработчика.

Если написать полный адрес от корня сервера (/lesson04/guestbook/addentry.php), отправка срабатывает тоже.

Наконец, если указать полный адрес обработчика (http://php1.local/lesson04/guestbook/addentry.php), форма тоже нормально отправляется.

Ситуация меняется, если в action написать echo **DIR** . '/addentry.php' (естественно, с подчёркиваниями и тегами PHP, при написании чего-то удалились). Тогда получается что-то вроде E:\OpenServer\domains\php1.local\lesson04\guestbook/addentry.php. Форма перестаёт отправляться. В чём тут дело?

Вначале думал, что в слеше, хотя читал, что PHP сам как-то слеши разруливает, поменял слеш на виндовый, ситуация не поменялась. Попробовал вместо button использовать submit, форма так и не отправляется.

Непонятно, что делать, так как по условию задачи надо работать с **DIR**. Кроме того, при работе с файлами или incllude никаких проблем с **DIR** не возникает.

Comment: надо писать адрес от корня сервера и все. Если у вас в условии задачи что то про dir, значит оно применяется в каком-то другом месте.

Comment: От корня в итоге и сделал. Однако не является ли такое решение негибким в перспективе? В смысле если придется много всего править и переносить, не приведет ли такое жесткое задание путей к плохой поддержке кода?

Comment: если писать плохой код, то негибки может стать любое решение. Тем не менее с такими путями зато всегда все понятно, в относительные могут привести к какой-нить путанице.

Comment: Иными словами, в путях от корня нет ничего плохого и в больших проектах их тоже активно используют?

Comment: в современных реалиях большинство проектов строится на различных фреймворках, так что пути руками крайне редко указываются.

Comment: Это понятно, но под "капотом" фреймворков прописываются от корня?

Comment: да, под капотом от корня